# Running Multiple versions of jQuery at the same time

Tags: jquery

I need to run two versions of jQuery. I've tried aliasing j to jQuery. Here is my code.

```
j = jQuery.noConflict(); // No conflict with older version of jQuery
(function($) {
  $('#any_id_or_class').on("click", function(event){
    console.log('clicked');
  });
})(j);
```

I've logged the version of jQuery using $.fn.jquery and I get two distinct versions depending if I log from inside my function or outside the scope. If I put a click to the 'body' of the document $('body') I get output, but here's where it all goes wrong, if I use any class or id on the page nothing happens? Ideas?

**Edit 1:** Obviously I would like to use only one version of jQuery, but that isn't an option.

**Edit 2:** Here's how I got it working, not ideal, as I wanted to try and alias the $ within the scope of the function.

```
j = jQuery.noConflict(); // No conflict with older version of jQuery

j(document).ready(function(){
  j('#masthead').on("click", function(event){
    console.log('clicked');
  });
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the newer version and map any deprecated function you are relying on to there newer counterpart?

Comment: _"but here's where it all goes wrong"_ **It went wrong from the beginning!**

Comment: or better yet update the plugin/codebase to be compatible OR if all else fails use the docs from the older version and fall back on that?

Comment: No offense ment, but this just sounds like **horrible** practice

Comment: Yes, if I could just use the newest version of jQuery that would be great, but I can't make that call and I need the newest version for this particular feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict(); // Unbinds the last included version of Jquery

  j('#any_id_or_class').on("click", function(event){
    console.log('clicked');
  });
```

The noConflict assignment will de-register the last included jquery file, so make sure the last included one is the new version to work with .on

Comment: Ah, that's probably the issue, but that still doesn't solve the issue of needing two versions.

Comment: It should do. If you include two jquerys and use the noconflict as above, anything after that using $("") will use the first jquery, anything using j("") will use the second. Im not exactly sure what is wrong with using the classes/ids - are there any console errors? are you using the $() or the j()? You did define the j as a var, as i put above; var j = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: I've aliased the whole function to j, so I should still be able to use $ within it. I'll try just using j.

Comment: DON'T FORGET to pass `true` to `noConflict(true)` so any previous version of jQuery get reassigned to `$` and/or `jQuery`.
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page