# jquery conflicts in header file

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

Hi i am using jquery week calendar and php calendar but i am getting conflicts if put query files like this.

in my header.phtml file the code is

```
<head>  
<?php
echo $this->headTitle('dddd');
$this->headMeta()
        ->setHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8')
        ->appendName('keywords', '')
        ->appendName('author', '')
        ->appendName('copyright', '')
        ->appendName('description', '');
$this->headLink()->headLink(array('rel' => 'favicon', 'href' => '/favicon.ico'), 'PREPEND');
$this->headLink()                
            ->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl.'/styles/layout.css', 'all')
            ->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl.'/scripts/jquery/jquery.css', 'all');

$this->headScript()->appendFile('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js');
$this->headScript()->appendFile('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js);           

$oFront = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance(); 
if($oFront->getRouter()->getCurrentRouteName() == "template-schedules-edit-template-schedule" ){
    $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl.'/scripts/jquery/plugins/weekcalendar/jquery-ui.min.js');
}else{
    $this->headScript()->appendFile('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.19/jquery-ui.min.js');
}        

echo $this->headMeta();
echo $this->headLink();
echo $this->headScript();
?> 
</head>
```

here i am using jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js for jquery week calendar and jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js for php canlender..

please help me out. its my first question in stack over flow.

/uday

Comment: Why do you use 2 versions of jQuery ?

Comment: Have a look at [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: Hi Bergi, how can i use jQuery.noConflict() here..

Answer (score 2):

You don't need both versions of jQuery. Just use one and you should be fine. Get rid of the following line:

```
$this->headScript()->appendFile('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js);
```

Comment: hi SpaceBeers, if i remove jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js this one drag nd drop and resize is not working in week calender.

Comment: What about if you remove the newer version?

Comment: Sorry, this is a bit too localised to offer any proper help without seeing the site. Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating new code you should be avoiding using 2 versions of jQuery (use the latest and adapt as needed).  If for some reason or another you're stuck with both (intractable legacy code), there's information on having 2 versions co-exist: [Running Multiple versions of jQuery at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9813311/1655332)